# Is there a connector to Azure AppInsights for VM Sitecore Instances

Tags: azure, logging, amazon-web-services, app-insight

We are currently running Sitecore 9.0 on AWS instances but will be moving to 9.3 on Azure.  We have 4 production CD servers, so tracking down issues in the log files is tedious to say the least, as we have to visit 4 servers.

Prior to the transition, we would like to start putting the 9.0 log information into AppInsights, to take advantage of the better logging facilities it provides.  Is there a connector that does this for us available now?  Would we have to roll our own?

Comment: Application Insights is not specific to having your site hosted on Azure PaaS. Just spin up an AI instance and install the configs/DLLs (ApplicationInsights.config, appinsights.instrumentationkey in connectionstrings.config, some configs in App_Config/Sitecore depending on your version, and some DLLs)

Comment: If you're on 9.3, you'd need some configs in App_Config/Sitecore/Azure, and any of the DLLs with AI and ApplicationInsights